# ASP.Net - How can I send an e-mail from SMTP server in Windows Server 2008 R2 (MX Record)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, windows-server-2008-r2

Hello I have a hosted Windows Server 2008 R2 and a purchased domain name. I have pointed my domain A, CNAME and MX records to my server's DNS. Now I'm trying to send an e-mail from an ASP.Net (C#) page. The SMTP server is my MX record (which points to A record). I have been trying everything and I'm still getting an error `5.7.3 Client was not authenticated`. I have tried Standard Authentication, Windows Integrated Authentication and I'm still getting this error. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: You have to make your account less secured.

Comment: Less secured how? Anonymous authentication?

Comment: Check the resolutions provided in the below link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760055/server-does-not-support-secure-connections-in-c-sharp